# MongoDB aggregate count of items in two arrays across different documents?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Here is my MongoDB collection schema:

```
company: String
model: String
cons: [String] // array of tags that were marked as "cons"
pros: [String] // array of tags that were marked as "pros"
```

I need to aggregate it so I get the following output:

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "company": "Lenovo",
    "model": "T400"
  },
  "tags": {
    tag: "SomeTag"
    pros: 124 // number of times, "SomeTag" tag was found in "pros" array in `Lenovo T400`
    cons: 345 // number of times, "SomeTag" tag was found in "cons" array in `Lenovo T400`
  }
}...]
```

I tried to do the following:

```
var aggParams = {};
aggParams.push({ $unwind: '$cons' });
aggParams.push({ $unwind: '$pros' });
aggParams.push({$group: {
  _id: {
    company: '$company',
    model: '$model',
    consTag: '$cons'
  },
  consTagCount: { $sum: 1 }
}});
aggParams.push({$group: {
  _id: {
    company: '$_id.company',
    model: '$_id.model',
    prosTag: '$pros'
  },
  prosTagCount: { $sum: 1 }
}});
aggParams.push({$group: {
  _id: {
    company:'$_id.company',
    model: '$_id.model'
  },
  tags: { $push: { tag: { $or: ['$_id.consTag', '$_id.prosTag'] }, cons: '$consTagCount', pros: '$prosTagCount'} }
}});
```

But I got the following result:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "company": "Lenovo",
    "model": "T400"
  },
  "tags": [
    {
      "tag": false,
      "pros": 7
    }
  ]
}
```

**What is the right way to do this with `aggregation`?**

Comment: Can we presume here that the "tag" in either "pros" or "cons" is unique within either array, or in fact "unique" in both? Per document of course.

Comment: Correct, tags are unique per document ("unique" in both arrays)

Comment: So to just be complely clear. "SomeTag" will only ever appear in say "pros" and not "cons" only once per document?

Comment: @BlakesSeven no, a single tag may appear in both "pros" and "cons"

Comment: That is okay if it can appear in both. The key element here is that it never appears in say "pros" more than once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is a bit harder considering that there are multiple arrays, and if you try both at the same time you end up with a "cartesian condition" where one arrray multiplies the contents of the other.

Therefore, just combine the array content at the beginning, which probably indicates how you should be storing the data in the first place:

```
Model.aggregate(
    [
        { "$project": {
            "company": 1,
            "model": 1,
            "data": {
                "$setUnion": [
                    { "$map": {
                        "input": "$pros",
                        "as": "pro",
                        "in": {
                            "type": { "$literal": "pro" },
                            "value": "$$pro"
                        }
                    }},
                    { "$map": {
                        "input": "$cons",
                        "as": "con",
                        "in": {
                            "type": { "$literal": "con" },
                            "value": "$$con"
                        }
                    }}
                ]
            }
        }},
        { "$unwind": "$data" }
        { "$group": {
            "_id": { 
                "company": "$company",
                "model": "$model",
                "tag": "$data.value"
            },
            "pros": { 
                "$sum": { 
                    "$cond": [
                        { "$eq": [ "$data.type", "pro" ] },
                        1,
                        0
                    ]
                }
            },
            "cons": { 
                "$sum": { 
                    "$cond": [
                        { "$eq": [ "$data.type", "con" ] },
                        1,
                        0
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ], 
    function(err,result) {

    }
)
```

So via the first [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage the [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operators are adding the "type" value to each item of each array. Not that it really matters here as all items should process "unique" anyway, the [**`$setUnion`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/) operator "contatenates" each array into a singular array.

As mentioned earlier, you probably should be storing in this way in the first place.

Then process [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) followed by [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/group/), wherein each "pros" and "cons" is then evaluated via [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) to for it's matching "type", either returning `1` or `0` where the match is respectively `true/false` to the [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) aggregation accumulator.

This gives you a "logical match" to count each respective "type" within the aggregation operation as per the grouping keys specified.

Comment: here is the output:
`{
            "_id": {
                "company": "Lenovo",
                "model": "T400",
                "tag": "Quality"
            },
            "pros": 132,
            "cons": 324
        }`

Comment: @MikeVayvala So? What is the point? This should be what you want, despite your "required output" not being really ideal again. Each "pro" and "con" is counted as per the grouping keys. And that is essentially what you asked for.